# LinkedIn share button alignment

Tags: html, css, linkedin-api

I am having trouble aligning LinkedIn share button on a website. Check the screenshot below -
[image: LinkedIn share button misalignment]

You can find it live [here](http://gautamthapar.me/). The button aligns well on other parts of that page but when it is placed above or below title then it somehow misbehaves.

How can I fix this?

Comment: try to reduce upper margin of inShare box

Comment: margin is already 0. Did you check it live?

Comment: Try to add Title in separate tag

Comment: I don't think it would be possible since the buttons are hooked into title. Buttons can be placed after or before title text. Can something be done with button container so that all buttons are aligned properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all those who tried to help! I finally managed to get it aligned.

**Solution:**
Since the issue occurs only when the buttons are positioned above or below title text so first of all I programatically added a custom class to the LinkedIn button container - `btnsx-li-height`. Then I applied the below CSS -

```
.btnsx-li-height .IN-widget {
    position: relative;
}
.btnsx-li-height .IN-widget > span > span > span {
    position: absolute;
    left: -30px;
    bottom: -20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will solve your problem

```
span.IN-widget > span{
  display:block !important;
}
```

Then clear `<br>` whick is between them and don't forget to clear element style to `display`.

Comment: That markup is generated by LinkedIn script so I cannot remove `<br>` tag or any other thing.

Comment: @Addicted try this : span.IN-widget > br {
  display:none !important;
}

Comment: I think I found my answer but I will try your as well. Between what do you mean by `clear element style to display` ?

Comment: there are some element style's on spans, display one of them and their value is inline-block. I meant them :) sorry, my english is not well

Answer (score 1):

In a custom CSS file, add the following:

```
.IN-widget > span > span {
  height: 30px;
}
```

Make sure the Custom CSS file order is the last.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Inline style will always override style from external file (tried though).

Comment: If you have `!important` in inline as well, yes it would. I have changed the code so you can target the span which doesn't have that property already.

Comment: @RachelGallen If you look at his markup, there is no inline style for the classes we both mentioned. The code I gave didn't work for him. So I had to change the code for him. Went offtopic: If inline style has `!important` already, we have no choice. Had to clear this one for him.

Comment: @ManojKumar all inline styles are added by LinkedIn script while generating the button so I have no control over that. But your solution did work but it made the button below content to appear like this - [LinkedIn Share Button](http://i.imgur.com/xo1Yn5I.png)

Comment: Just thought it was a handy link!

Comment: Can you try again with updated code? @RachelGallen Oh I see! :)

Comment: So I modified your solution. `.btnsx-li-height .IN-widget > span { height: 28px; }`. Thanks this somehow fixes the problem.

Comment: That's good. Not sure why this answer versions won't work. Still not taking the priority maybe.